# right to left excel page layout in python xlwt

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

How can set the sheet layout ( right-to-left ) by using xlwt ?

i am using xlwt for writing an excel sheet, but my data is right to left and i want to set sheet layout right to left ( same as microsoft excel's Page layout tab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
for shx in 0, 1:
    ws = wb.add_sheet("S%d" % shx)
    # Excel 2003: Tools > Options > International > View current sheet right-to-left
    # Excel 2007: Page Layout > Sheet Right-to-Left
    ws.cols_right_to_left = shx
    ws.write(0, 0, "qwerty")
wb.save("colsR2L.xls")
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, a sheet right-to-left is false, to set it true:

```
import xlwt
wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet("sheet", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
sheet.cols_right_to_left = True
wbk.save("testRTL.xls")
```